# Convert list of dicts into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am trying to convert the list of dicts that I get from my code here. I tried converting my results to DataFrame and all I get is CatBoost results, the other two models are not recorded. The results are a list of dicts that I cannot convert to clean DataFrame.

```
models = [('LogisticRegressor', LogisticRegression()),
         ('RandomForest', RandomForestClassifier()),
         ('CatBoost', CatBoostClassifier(silent=True))]
dfs=[]
results=[]
names=[]
scoring=['accuracy', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1']

for name, model in models:
    cv_results = cross_validate(model, X_train, y_train, scoring=scoring,
                               cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
    clf = model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
df1=pd.DataFrame(cv_results)
df1['model'] = name
dfs.append(df1)

results
[{'fit_time': array([0.03125048, 0.03125048, 0.03125048, 0.03125048, 0.        ]),
  'score_time': array([0.        , 0.01562595, 0.        , 0.        , 0.01562405]),
  'test_accuracy': array([0.71544715, 0.77235772, 0.73170732, 0.77235772, 0.75409836]),
  'test_precision': array([0.59459459, 0.74193548, 0.63888889, 0.75862069, 0.67647059]),
  'test_recall': array([0.52380952, 0.53488372, 0.53488372, 0.51162791, 0.54761905]),
  'test_f1': array([0.55696203, 0.62162162, 0.58227848, 0.61111111, 0.60526316])},
 {'fit_time': array([0.28125215, 0.29687738, 0.29687738, 0.29687738, 0.15625048]),
  'score_time': array([0.03125119, 0.03125095, 0.01562595, 0.03125095, 0.01564193]),
  'test_accuracy': array([0.72357724, 0.69918699, 0.69918699, 0.77235772, 0.75409836]),
  'test_precision': array([0.58695652, 0.58333333, 0.57894737, 0.72727273, 0.6875    ]),
  'test_recall': array([0.64285714, 0.48837209, 0.51162791, 0.55813953, 0.52380952]),
  'test_f1': array([0.61363636, 0.53164557, 0.54320988, 0.63157895, 0.59459459])},
 {'fit_time': array([2.26015663, 2.26015663, 2.26115775, 2.3036592 , 1.60637379]),
  'score_time': array([0.00900555, 0.00900555, 0.00900674, 0.00900674, 0.00500464]),
  'test_accuracy': array([0.71544715, 0.72357724, 0.71544715, 0.76422764, 0.75409836]),
  'test_precision': array([0.57777778, 0.62162162, 0.61111111, 0.71875   , 0.6875    ]),
  'test_recall': array([0.61904762, 0.53488372, 0.51162791, 0.53488372, 0.52380952]),
  'test_f1': array([0.59770115, 0.575     , 0.55696203, 0.61333333, 0.59459459])}]
```

Comment: Would the output be three rows with lists of 5 in each cell or 15 rows of values. 6 columns?

Comment: Per my comment, my answer is for the latter.  For the former, just exclude the part of the code where you explode. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In short you can do:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(results)
      .assign(model=model_names)
      .apply(pd.Series.explode))
df
```

Full reproducible example below with output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
results = [{'fit_time': np.array([0.03125048, 0.03125048, 0.03125048, 0.03125048, 0.        ]),
  'score_time': np.array([0.        , 0.01562595, 0.        , 0.        , 0.01562405]),
  'test_accuracy': np.array([0.71544715, 0.77235772, 0.73170732, 0.77235772, 0.75409836]),
  'test_precision': np.array([0.59459459, 0.74193548, 0.63888889, 0.75862069, 0.67647059]),
  'test_recall': np.array([0.52380952, 0.53488372, 0.53488372, 0.51162791, 0.54761905]),
  'test_f1': np.array([0.55696203, 0.62162162, 0.58227848, 0.61111111, 0.60526316])},
 {'fit_time': np.array([0.28125215, 0.29687738, 0.29687738, 0.29687738, 0.15625048]),
  'score_time': np.array([0.03125119, 0.03125095, 0.01562595, 0.03125095, 0.01564193]),
  'test_accuracy': np.array([0.72357724, 0.69918699, 0.69918699, 0.77235772, 0.75409836]),
  'test_precision': np.array([0.58695652, 0.58333333, 0.57894737, 0.72727273, 0.6875    ]),
  'test_recall': np.array([0.64285714, 0.48837209, 0.51162791, 0.55813953, 0.52380952]),
  'test_f1': np.array([0.61363636, 0.53164557, 0.54320988, 0.63157895, 0.59459459])},
 {'fit_time': np.array([2.26015663, 2.26015663, 2.26115775, 2.3036592 , 1.60637379]),
  'score_time': np.array([0.00900555, 0.00900555, 0.00900674, 0.00900674, 0.00500464]),
  'test_accuracy': np.array([0.71544715, 0.72357724, 0.71544715, 0.76422764, 0.75409836]),
  'test_precision': np.array([0.57777778, 0.62162162, 0.61111111, 0.71875   , 0.6875    ]),
  'test_recall': np.array([0.61904762, 0.53488372, 0.51162791, 0.53488372, 0.52380952]),
  'test_f1': np.array([0.59770115, 0.575     , 0.55696203, 0.61333333, 0.59459459])}]
model_names = ['LogisticRegressor', 'RandomForest', 'CatBoost']
df = (pd.DataFrame(results)
      .assign(model=model_names)
      .apply(pd.Series.explode))
df
Out[1]: 
   fit_time score_time test_accuracy test_precision test_recall   test_f1  \
0  0.031250   0.000000      0.715447       0.594595    0.523810  0.556962   
0  0.031250   0.015626      0.772358       0.741935    0.534884  0.621622   
0  0.031250   0.000000      0.731707       0.638889    0.534884  0.582278   
0  0.031250   0.000000      0.772358       0.758621    0.511628  0.611111   
0  0.000000   0.015624      0.754098       0.676471    0.547619  0.605263   
1  0.281252   0.031251      0.723577       0.586957    0.642857  0.613636   
1  0.296877   0.031251      0.699187       0.583333    0.488372  0.531646   
1  0.296877   0.015626      0.699187       0.578947    0.511628  0.543210   
1  0.296877   0.031251      0.772358       0.727273    0.558140  0.631579   
1  0.156250   0.015642      0.754098       0.687500    0.523810  0.594595   
2  2.260157   0.009006      0.715447       0.577778    0.619048  0.597701   
2  2.260157   0.009006      0.723577       0.621622    0.534884  0.575000   
2  2.261158   0.009007      0.715447       0.611111    0.511628  0.556962   
2  2.303659   0.009007      0.764228       0.718750    0.534884  0.613333   
2  1.606374   0.005005      0.754098       0.687500    0.523810  0.594595   

               model  
0  LogisticRegressor  
0  LogisticRegressor  
0  LogisticRegressor  
0  LogisticRegressor  
0  LogisticRegressor  
1       RandomForest  
1       RandomForest  
1       RandomForest  
1       RandomForest  
1       RandomForest  
2           CatBoost  
2           CatBoost  
2           CatBoost  
2           CatBoost  
2           CatBoost
```